# How to fix the encoding issue when piping with external programs in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to use `Out-String` to save the output of `ffprobe` as a string in PowerShell.
(`ffprobe` can output the metadata of a media file.)

The output contains non-Latin characters, but when I use `Out-String`, the characters are not displayed correctly and are replaced with question marks.

For example, the output of the `ffprobe $filename` command when run alone is:

```yaml
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc59.20.100 libopus
  ALBUM           : 钗头凤
  ARTIST          : 等什么君
  comment         : 酷我音乐
  TITLE           : 钗头凤
```

But when I use `ffprobe $filename 2>&1 | Out-String`, the output is displayed as:

```yaml
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc59.20.100 libopus
  ALBUM           : 閽楀ご鍑?
  ARTIST          : 绛変粈涔堝悰
  comment         : 閰锋垜闊充箰
  TITLE           : 閽楀ご鍑?
```

I suspect that the issue is with the encoding used by PowerShell when converting the ffprobe output to a string. No matter with or without `Out-String`, the issue has appeared.

Similar problem can be found when running scripts that output non-Latin characters. For example, when I run

```
Write-Output 'Non-latin characters like Cyrillic (Д, Ц); CJK characters (本, 화, が).'
```

the output is fine. However, when I save the script to a file (test.ps1) and run it using the `.\test.ps1` command, the output is displayed with encoding errors.

```
Non-latin characters like Cyrillic (袛, 笑); CJK characters (鏈?, 頇?, 銇?).
```

My `$OutputEncoding` variable is set to `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8`

```yaml
BodyName          : utf-8
EncodingName      : Unicode (UTF-8)
HeaderName        : utf-8
WebName           : utf-8
WindowsCodePage   : 1200
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
IsSingleByte      : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 65001
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to fix this encoding issue?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It is a Font issue when display character in PS.  Need to change the Font in PS.Right click on the PowerShell icon at the top left of the PowerShell screen.
Click Properties.
A window appears, showing options for font size, family, colors and more.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for response. That doesn't work. As I said it works fine when I just type `Write-Output 'ДЦ本화が'` in the console, which means that the font can display the characters properly.

Comment: Maybe it is a Big/Little Endian issue?  Maybe following will help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_character_encoding?view=powershell-7.3  It may be Standard Output is using a different console from PS.

Comment: @jdweng I set `$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'utf8'` and `[console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding` and both not working

Comment: Does this answer your question?: [Using UTF-8 Encoding (CHCP 65001) in Command Prompt / Windows Powershell (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/1701026)